# Pipeline execution error from scheduled trigger

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My azure data factory pipeline runs as expected when triggered manually but when the scheduled trigger runs I run into the below error and hit a roadblock on how
best to troubleshoot this error because the manual trigger succeeds with no errors. And scheduled triggers throw errors. The step where I encounter the error is lookup activity. I'm trying to retrieve a record from a table using a SQL query.

I checked the access and no real difference there as it has ***contributor*** rights.

Not sure what might be causing this error when run from scheduled trigger?

[image]

***Error:***

> Operation on target Lookup activity failed: ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,
> 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property '' is invalid:
> 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'.,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.SecurityValidation.Exceptions.HostValidationException,
> Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.SecurityValidation,'

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is it's possible that the scheduled trigger encounters issues due to the state of the data at the time of execution.

Also check the time zone settings of your scheduled trigger and ensure that it aligns with your expectations.

Please check input parameters or values being used in the lookup activity. Make sure they are correct and within the expected range.

I have scheduled a  pipeline that moves data from SQL database to Azure Datalake storage.

[image]

[image]
[image]
**Manual trigger and Schedule Trigger:**
[image]

**Schedule Trigger:**

[image]
**Output as per the Lookup activity Query:**
[image]